# Extended Kalman Filter - how do I get transition functions

Tags: kalman-filters, tracking

I am measuring position and velocity, both have some noise in them. Velocity is defined as derivative of position. The system is apparently non-linear so I need to use EKF.

**Model:**

\begin{align}
X&=\begin{bmatrix}p\\v\end{bmatrix}\\
p_{k+1}&=A_0\sin\left(b_0k\right)+A_1\sin\left(b_1k\right)+A_2\sin\left(b_2k\right)\\
v_{k+1}&=A_0b_0\cos\left(b_0k\right)+A_1b_1\cos\left(b_1k\right)+A_2b_2\cos\left(b_2k\right)\\
\end{align}

**Questions:**

1. I suppose this is a non-linear system. Am I right?
2. If yes, I should use Extended Kalman filter. But how do I get $f$ and $h$ functions for my case (below)? The current state doesn't depend on previous state; except the $k$ (step) variable.
   \begin{align}
   x_k&=f\left(x_{k-1}\right)+w_k\\
   z_k&=h\left(x_k\right)+v_k
   \end{align}

Comment: Your current state should depend upon its previous state, or a Kalman filter isn't going to help you much. Try solving for $p_{k+1}$ in terms of $p_k$ and so on. This would yield the state transition equation, which is an important part of the model.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I was concerned this wouldn't be applicable for Kalman's filter.